# merge Subsequent segments by value

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame()` with segments and values.
I want to merge the segments if there value is close enough.

Reproducible example-

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(start = seq(from = 1, to = 91, by = 10),
                 end = seq(from = 10, to = 100, by = 10),
                 value = rnorm(10))

print(df)
   start end      value
1      1  10  0.2167549
2     11  20 -0.5424926
3     21  30  0.8911446
4     31  40  0.5959806
5     41  50  1.6356180
6     51  60  0.6892754
7     61  70 -1.2812466
8     71  80 -0.2131445
9     81  90  1.8965399
10    91 100  1.7768632
```

difference between subsequent segments is

```
for(i in 1:9) print(abs(df$value[i] - df$value[i+1]))
[1] 0.7592474
[1] 1.433637
[1] 0.2951641
[1] 1.039637
[1] 0.9463426
[1] 1.970522
[1] 1.068102
[1] 2.109684
[1] 0.1196767
```

let say that I want to merge segments that the diff is smaller than 1, and the value should be the mean of the segments values.
result should look like this-

```
  start end      value
1     1  20 -0.1628689
2    21  40  0.7435626
3    41  60  1.1624467
4    61  70 -1.2812466
5    71  80 -0.2131445
6    81  10  1.8367015
```

If there are 3 segments one after the other, I would like to merge the three of the into one.

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution.. 
The variable `weight` represent the number of merge segment.

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(start = seq(from = 1, to = 91, by = 10),
                 end = seq(from = 10, to = 100, by = 10),
                 value = rnorm(10))


df$weight <- 1 #initialize the number of merge segment

for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){

  if (abs(df$value[i] - df$value[i+1]) < 1 & df$weight[i] < 3) {
  #the second part of the condition limit a 3 the maximum number of segement merge (can be change to x segment) 

    df$end[i] <- df$end[i+1]
    df$value[i] <- weighted.mean(df$value[c(i, i+1)],df$weight[c(i, i+1)] ) 
    df$weight[i] <- df$weight[i]+1
    df[i+1,] <- df[i,]
    df[i,]$weight <- 0 

    }

}
df <- df[df$weight > 0,]
```

Comment: @T.G. I edit the response so you can define the maximum number of merged segment.

Comment: thank you!
I thought R might have some kind of a built in but it's a great solution.

Comment: @T.G. I don't think there would be any specific fonction for that, but you can considere using the package `data.table` or `dplyr` if you need to improve the performance

Comment: Just for run-time reasons, I would change the i+1 row immediately, instead of updating the i'th row, and coping it in the end.

    df$start[i+1] <- df$start[i]
    df$value[i+1] <- weighted.mean(df$value[c(i, i+1)],df$weight[c(i, i+1)] ) 
    df$weight[i+1] <- df$weight[i+1]+1
    df[i,]$weight <- 0